# Order Mail Payment method Section is empty For BarclayCard Payment

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, order-email

I am using magento 1.9 version.

I have used [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/barclaycard-epdq-payment-gateway-free.html) BarclayCard Payment Extension.

It works fine in Frontend OnePageCheckOut, Captures the Payment But in the Order Email, Payment method Section is empty. What willbe the issue. How to Fix it.

[image: mail Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension Doesn't have the phtml file specified in

```
app/code/local/Juicy/Barclayspspid/Block/Form.php.
```

ie.,

```
$this->setTemplate('barclayspspid/form.phtml');
```

By Adding the missed phtml file in

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourpackage/template/barclayspspid/form.phtml
```

with the following content solved my issue.

```
<p><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></p>
```